# Extra spacing between buttons ONLY on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, button, mobile, responsive

I'm having a difficult time debugging this issue. I need my buttons to be both touching and stacked horizontally. On desktop browsers, I get something similar to the following:

```css
#aWrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.buttons {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
<div id="aWrapper">
  <button class="buttons">Button 1</button>
  <button class="buttons">Button 2</button>
</div>
```

Which is what I want! But on mobile browsers (Chrome, Safari, Opera Mini, and Firefox) on iOS I get this result with the EXACT same code (I added a margin on purpose to illustrate):

```css
#aWrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.buttons {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  
  margin-right: 4px; /*IGNORE THIS*/
 }
```

```html
<div id="aWrapper">
  <button class="buttons">Button 1</button>
  <button class="buttons">Button 2</button>
</div>
```

Why is this happening? I saw from other answers that white-white space might be an issue, but it's not in this case.

Here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ajarana/pen/ZKLLQq) showing this in action. Open it in a desktop browser, then open it on an iOS device using any browser. There should be extra spacing between the buttons in the mobile browser, and they should be touching in the desktop browser.

NOTE: The answer I marked correct works fine, but `display: flex` ALSO works on the wrapper, I just wasn't importing my css normalizer file correctly, leading to this unnecessary headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm

since i dont have any ios device to test, but this is what i expect to work

```
#aWrapper .buttons{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}
#aWrapper{
  clear: both;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e08buvp5/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on desktop. There's spacing between the buttons, I want them to be touching.

Comment: my bad.. change `buttons` to  `.buttons` in css code + added demo link for reference

Comment: why not.. i made my buttons `inline-block` so it will take only width which is necessary  for them and float them left to keep them in one line

Comment: Is there any way I can make this work using display:flex on my wrapper, though?

Comment: I dont have much experience with flex thing so i really dont have any idea